# how to send published data to another program

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a c++ program that uses a transform listener to publish data as topics. I want to know how I can (if possible) use this data that is published as input to another program. This means as the first program is publishing the data the new program is also receiving this data.

If you need any more clarification feel free to ask and any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255904/how-to-send-published-data-to-another-program/) by [fundamentals](https://answers.ros.org/users/29111/fundamentals/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would take a look at this: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20(C%2B%2B). It is a tutorial on how to subscribe to frame transformations.

---

Originally posted by [dambrosio](https://answers.ros.org/users/19732/dambrosio/) with karma: 161 on 2017-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes; the first program can use a publisher to send the data, and the second program can have a subscriber that subscribes to that data.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1